# Generate QR using VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, qr-code

I am using this code to generate QR in excel.
However I can't make it to generate only if the QR not present in column "example: F2" if the QR already present skip to next cell. Because it keeps generating whenever I click the generate button and make it overlap with the old/present QR.
Glad if someone could help me with this. As I've been stuck here for about a weeks.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub QRGEN()

Sheet2.Activate
Dim c       As Range

Dim lRow    As Long
lRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(2, Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
For Each c In Range("F2:F" & lRow)
If c.Offset(0, -1) <> "" Then
    MakeQRCode sData:=c.Offset(0, -1).Text, _
    iForeCol:=vbBlack, iBackCol:=vbWhite, iSize:=60, cell:=c

End If

Next c

End Sub


Function MakeQRCode(sData As String, iForeCol As Long, iBackCol As Long, _
               ByVal iSize, cell As Range) As Boolean
Dim iPic          As Long
Dim sPic          As String
Dim oPic          As Picture
Dim sURL          As String

On Error Resume Next

Do
Set oPic = Nothing
iPic = iPic + 1
sPic = "QRCode(" & iPic & ")"
Set oPic = cell.Worksheet.Pictures(sPic)
Loop While Not oPic Is Nothing
err.Clear

If iSize > 1000 Then iSize = 1000
If iSize < 10 Then iSize = 10

sURL = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?" & _
     "&data=" & sData & _
     "&size=" & iSize & "x" & iSize & _
     "&charset-source=UTF-8" & _
     "&charset-target=UTF-8" & _
     "&ecc=L" & _
     "&color=" & sRGB(iForeCol) & _
     "&bgcolor=" & sRGB(iBackCol) & _
     "&margin=0" & _
     "&qzone=1" & _
     "&format=png"
' Debug.Print sURL

With cell.Worksheet.Pictures.Insert(sURL)
.Name = sPic
.Left = cell.Left + 10.5
.Top = cell.Top + 4
End With

MakeQRCode = err.Number = 0
End Function

Function sRGB(iRGB As Long) As String
' converts an RGB long to RRGGBB
sRGB = Right("00000" & Hex(iRGB), 6)
sRGB = Right(sRGB, 2) & Mid(sRGB, 3, 2) & Left(sRGB, 2)
End Function
```

Comment: Above is the code that fully work.. At first I've tried to add [code] If ActiveSheet.Pictures(i).Name = "QRCode" Then
            ActiveSheet.Pictures(i).Delete
            Exit For
        End If [\code] but it seems not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way, but not the most elegant one, is to add the next code on top of your `Sub QRGEN()` procedure:

```
Dim sh As Shape
 For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If InStr(sh.Name, "QRCode") > 0 Then sh.Delete
 Next
```

This will delete all your QRCode shapes and process everything again, but loosing time...

A better solution would be to create a function able to look for the QRCode picture checking its `Top` property, to be the one of the `cell.Top + 4`, like it has been defined in the running code. The problem is that if you move the pictures, the code would not return the correct result.
So, add the next function:

```
Function testQRCodeExistence(cell As Range) As Boolean
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If sh.top = cell.top + 4 Then testQRCodeExistence = True: Exit For
    Next
End Function
```

and add this lines on the existing code (easy to understand where...):

```
If c.Offset(0, -1) <> "" Then
    If Not testQRCodeExistence(c) Then
        MakeQRCode sData:=c.Offset(0, -1).Text, _
          iForeCol:=vbBlack, iBackCol:=vbWhite, iSize:=70, cell:=c
    End If
End If
```

But the best solution would be to name the QRCode picture in a different way. For instance, to be named `"QRCode" & Cell.Address`...
So, adapt the naming part in this way:

```
Do
    sPic = "QRCode(" & cell.Address & ")"
    Set oPic = cell.Worksheet.Pictures(sPic)
Loop While Not oPic Is Nothing
```

Create a new function looking for the `Cell.Addres` in the QR picture name:

```
Function checkQRPictExistence(cell As Range) As Boolean
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If InStr(sh.Name, cell.Address) > 0 Then checkQRPictExistence = True: Exit For
    Next
End Function
```

And insert the checking line like in above approach, but using this last function:

```
If c.Offset(0, -1) <> "" Then
    If Not checkQRPictExistence(c) Then
        MakeQRCode sData:=c.Offset(0, -1).Text, _
          iForeCol:=vbBlack, iBackCol:=vbWhite, iSize:=70, cell:=c
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help sir.. Previously I already used the "sh.delete" one but to generate 50++ would take 10-15 minutes.. and next I'm using the solution from the comment above to check if there's picture in cell it works thanks! to @peh. But yours is much better.. Thanks again sir!! Really appreciate it.. :D

Comment: @mohd aizat: Welcome! But, in order to work in (almost) any circumstances, there are some issues to be set and understood, I think: The default shape property must be "Move but don't size with cells". But what if you (somebody else) insert(s)/delete(s) some rows? It can be imagined a way to trigger rows insertion/deletion and correct the picture names according to the new situation. If interested, I can imagine something from this point of view. But, I could see that you did not press the answer up arrow even if you look to be satisfied about the code...

Comment: Dear sir, that would be a good idea.. Thanks for that.. I did press the answer up arrow but, since I am new in stack overflow, so it shows me this message when I click the UP arrow.. "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." I am sorry couldn't help much with that.. But, its recorded btw.. And I'll keep active here so that once I get more reputation I'll definitely come back to this.. :D